# "connection terminated unexpectedly" error with Node, Postgres on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, knex.js

I have a number of Node functions running on AWS Lambda. These functions have been using the Node 8 runtime but AWS sent out an end-of-life notice saying that functions should be upgraded to the latest LTS. With that, I upgraded one on my functions to use Node 12. After being in production for a bit, I'm starting to see a ton of `connection terminated unexpectedly` errors when querying the database.

Here are the errors that I'm seeing:

1. The `connection terminated` unexpectedly error
2. And `Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed` - this seems to happen on the 1st or second invocation after seeing the connection terminated unexpectedly error.

I'm using Knex.js for querying the database. I was running older version of `knex` and `node-postgres` and recently upgraded to see if it would resolve the issue, but no luck. Here are the versions of `knex` and `node-postgres` that I'm currently running:

`"knex": "^0.20.8"
"pg": "^7.17.1"`

The only change I've made to this particular function is the upgrade to Node 12. I've also tried Node 10, but the same issue persists. Unfortunately, AWS won't let me downgrade to Node 8 to verify that it is indeed an issue. None of my other functions running on Node 8 are experiencing this issue.

I've researched `knex`, `node-postgres` and `tarn.js` (the Knex connection pooling library) to see if any related issues or solutions popped up, but so far, I haven't had any luck.

UPDATE:

Example of a handler. Note that this is happening on many different Lambdas, all running Node 12.

```
require('../../helpers/knex')

const { Rollbar } = require('@scoutforpets/utils')
const { Email } = require('@scoutforpets/notifications')
const { transaction: tx } = require('objection')
const Invoice = require('../../models/invoice')

// configure rollbar for error logging
const rollbar = Rollbar.configureRollbar(process.env.ROLLBAR_TOKEN)

/**
 *
 * @param {*} event
 */
async function handler (event) {
  const { invoice } = event
  const { id: invoiceId } = invoice

  try {
    return tx(Invoice, async Invoice => {
      // send the receipt
      await Email.Customer.paymentReceipt(invoiceId, true)

      // convert JSON to model
      const i = Invoice.fromJson(invoice)

      // mark the invoice as having been sent
      await i.markAsSent()
    })
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

module.exports.handler = rollbar.lambdaHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with node.js 10 aws lambda make the `handler` async, so you have to adapt your code. 
Docs : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

> The runtime passes three arguments to the handler method. The first
>   argument is the event object, which contains information from the
>   invoker. The invoker passes this information as a JSON-formatted
>   string when it calls Invoke, and the runtime converts it to an object.
>   When an AWS service invokes your function, the event structure varies
>   by service.
>
> The second argument is the context object, which contains information
>   about the invocation, function, and execution environment. In the
>   preceding example, the function gets the name of the log stream from
>   the context object and returns it to the invoker.
>
> The third argument, callback, is a function that you can call in
>   non-async functions to send a response. The callback function takes
>   two arguments: an Error and a response. When you call it, Lambda waits
>   for the event loop to be empty and then returns the response or error
>   to the invoker. The response object must be compatible with
>   JSON.stringify.
>
> For async functions, you return a response, error, or promise to the
>   runtime instead of using callback.

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
  return context.logStreamName
}
```

Thx!

Comment: thanks but already doing this. i confirmed that switching back to node 8 fixes the underlying issue. still not sure why

Comment: great, can you share the handler function ?

Comment: Hi jdixon, look like rollbar had a couple of issues related to async handlers ( like node 10/12 https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js/issues/700 ). It's posible to try without rollbar?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the right connection pooling config.

See the docs here: https://github.com/marcogrcr/sequelize/blob/patch-1/docs/manual/other-topics/aws-lambda.md

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

let sequelize = null;

async function loadSequelize() {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* (...) */, {
    // (...)
    pool: {
      /*
       * Lambda functions process one request at a time but your code may issue multiple queries
       * concurrently. Be wary that `sequelize` has methods that issue 2 queries concurrently
       * (e.g. `Model.findAndCountAll()`). Using a value higher than 1 allows concurrent queries to
       * be executed in parallel rather than serialized. Careful with executing too many queries in
       * parallel per Lambda function execution since that can bring down your database with an
       * excessive number of connections.
       *
       * Ideally you want to choose a `max` number where this holds true:
       * max * EXPECTED_MAX_CONCURRENT_LAMBDA_INVOCATIONS < MAX_ALLOWED_DATABASE_CONNECTIONS * 0.8
       */
      max: 2,
      /*
       * Set this value to 0 so connection pool eviction logic eventually cleans up all connections
       * in the event of a Lambda function timeout.
       */
      min: 0,
      /*
       * Set this value to 0 so connections are eligible for cleanup immediately after they're
       * returned to the pool.
       */
      idle: 0,
      // Choose a small enough value that fails fast if a connection takes too long to be established.
      acquire: 3000,
      /*
       * Ensures the connection pool attempts to be cleaned up automatically on the next Lambda
       * function invocation, if the previous invocation timed out.
       */
      evict: CURRENT_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT
    }
  });

  // or `sequelize.sync()`
  await sequelize.authenticate();

  return sequelize;
}

module.exports.handler = async function (event, callback) {
  // re-use the sequelize instance across invocations to improve performance
  if (!sequelize) {
    sequelize = await loadSequelize();
  } else {
    // restart connection pool to ensure connections are not re-used across invocations
    sequelize.connectionManager.initPools();

    // restore `getConnection()` if it has been overwritten by `close()`
    if (sequelize.connectionManager.hasOwnProperty("getConnection")) {
      delete sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection;
    }
  }

  try {
    return await doSomethingWithSequelize(sequelize);
  } finally {
    // close any opened connections during the invocation
    // this will wait for any in-progress queries to finish before closing the connections
    await sequelize.connectionManager.close();
  }
};
```

It's actually for sequelize, not knex, but I'm sure under the hood they work the same way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29833536)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, in my case it was cause i tried to connect db in production.

so, I added ssl to Pool, like this:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString,
    ssl: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
});
```

Hope it helps you too...